# Trying to make a frosted glass effect in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

hi im trying to make a frosted glass effect but the blur filter doesnt seem to work and the background doesnt blur ive tried everything what do you think the problem is?
ive created the card using bootstrap

```
        .card {
        margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;      
    background-color: inherit;
    
    }
    .card::before{
        content: "";
        background-color: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
        filter: blur(40px) !important;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide html code or preferably a sandbox link, so that we can have a better picture of what you are doing and intending.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

We have used card for a glass effect and apply `backdrop-filter` property instead of `filter`

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/b5nazhv7/

You we also take reference from our "Glassmorphism" CodePen demo.
https://codepen.io/yudizsolutions/pen/qBqKGgM

Comment: thank you for your answer unfortunately backdrop-filter doesn't work with firefox do you by any chance have an alternative or something to also make it work on firefox?